# How to remove items from vector based on index

Tags: r

How do you remove items of a vector based on index?

```
x <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
items_to_remove <- c(2:3)
```

Desired output:

```
"a","d","e","f"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
x[-items_to_remove]
 "a" "d" "e" "f"
```